# Traversing two trees together?

Tags: algorithm

I am looking a lot of interview problems where the question requires traversing two trees together, I am not sure exactly how to go about doing this.

e.g.

> Given references to roots of two binary trees, how do you determine
>   whether the  sequence of the leaf elements equal but you must
>   implement short circuiting return when the first node violates the
>   rule.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is your question asking to find out whether:
"the sequence created by visiting all the leaf nodes of 2 trees is same"

with a constraint that when found a mismatch of leaf values, then we must quit immediately.

If so, I propose following solution:

```
insert (root of tree1) in stack1
insert (root of tree2) in stack2

temp1 = (root of tree1) -> left child
temp2 = (root of tree2) -> left child

while(stack1 and stack2 arent empty) 
{
    found = false
    while(found == false) {
        if (temp1 is leaf node)
            child1 = value of temp1
            found = true
            pop element from stack1
            set temp1 to its right child

        if (temp1 has left child)
            put temp1 in stack1
            set temp1 to its left child
    }

    found = false
    while(found == false) {
        if (temp2 is leaf node)
            child2 = value of temp2
            found = true
            pop element from stack2
            set temp2 to its right child

        if (temp2 has left child)
            put temp2 in stack2
            set temp2 to its left child
    }

    if(child1 != child2) 
        return
}
```

Comment: If temp1 is not leaf node and has only right (leaf) child, how would you reach there?

Answer (score 3):

One possible solution:

- I have created a tree class which has a method GetNextLeafNode(). This is responsible for returning the next immediate leaf node of a tree.
- With the tree class I am keeping a stack to maintain the traversed elements
- In the GetNextLeafNode() method, I am doing iterative tree traversal (Pre order).

Whenever I encounter a node(stack.Pop()) which is leaf I am just returning it. Otherwise I am pushing left and right pointers to the stack. Initially root node is pushed. At any time state of stack is proper.

Here is the code in C#:

```
    public TreeNode GetNextLeafNode()
    {
        TreeNode leaf = null;

        while (s.Count != 0)
        {
            TreeNode n = s.Pop();
            if ((n.Left == null) && (n.Right == null))
            {
                leaf = n;
                return leaf;
            }
            else
            {
                if (n.Right != null)
                    s.Push(n.Right);
                if (n.Left != null)
                    s.Push(n.Left);
            }
        }

        return leaf;
    }
```

Now, we can create two different trees say, t1 and t2.
We can do the comparision as follows:

```
        int data1 = t1.GetNextLeafNode().Data;
        int data2 = t2.GetNextLeafNode().Data;

        while (data1 == data2)
        {
            //both the leaf nodes are same.
            data1 = t1.GetNextLeafNode().Data;
            data2 = t2.GetNextLeafNode().Data;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

In pseudo-code:

1. Go down to the first leaf (let's say left-most) in each tree.
2. Compare.
3. If not equal RETURN error.
4. Step to the next leaf in each tree (intuitively -- go up until you see a way to step to the right child, then take only left children on your way till you reach a leaf).
5. If one of the trees has a leaf but another returned to root RETURN error.
6. If both trees returned to root RETURN success.
7. Go to step 2.

Comment: The solution you suggested sounds good to me, The step 4 appears to be doable through IN order traversal.

Answer (score 0):

A simple python solution. 
Though this is not space optimal as we are storing leaves that can be O(N+M). This is not iterating both the trees together.
Time complexity - O(N+M).

You can also think of a solution where space is O(max(N,M)) in a similar fashion.

```
def binaryTreeLeafs(root1, root2):

    # The order in which we see leaves will
    # be maintained as it is inorder traversal.
    def dfs(node, leaves):
        if not node:
            return
        if not node.left and not node.right:
            leaves.append(node.val)
            return
        dfs(node.left, leaves)
        dfs(node.right, leaves)

    leaves1 = []
    leaves2 = []
    dfs(root1, leaves1)
    dfs(root2, leaves2)
    return leaves1 == leaves2


# O(h1+h2) space
def binaryTreeLeaves2(root1, root2):
    def isLeaf(node):
        return not node or node.left == node.right == None
    if not root1 and not root2:
        return True
    if (not root1) ^ (not root2):
        return False
    stack1 = [root1]
    stack2 = [root2]
    while stack1 or stack2:
        if (not stack1) ^ (not stack2):
            return False
        tmp1 = stack1.pop()
        while not isLeaf(tmp1):
            if tmp1.right:
                stack1.append(tmp1.right)
            if tmp1.left:
                stack1.append(tmp1.left)
            tmp1 = stack1.pop()
        tmp2 = stack2.pop()
        while not isLeaf(tmp2):
            if tmp2.right:
                stack2.append(tmp2.right)
            if tmp2.left:
                stack2.append(tmp2.left)
            tmp2 = stack2.pop()
        if ((not tmp1) ^ (not tmp2)) or (tmp1 and tmp2 and tmp1.val != tmp2.val):
            return False        
    return True
```